# JSON serializer adds its own $ids to my objects

Tags: .net, json

I serialize my entity by `JSON(listOfObjects)` however I keep getting additional ids in my JSON structure.

For class

```
   [JsonObject(IsReference = true)]
    public class User
    { 
        public Guid id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string picture { get; set; }
        public string email { get; set; }
        public string skypeLink { get; set; }
        public string title { get; set; }
        public string location { get; set; }
        public string products { get; set; }
        public string organizationUnit { get; set; }
        public string skills { get; set; }
        public string hobbies { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Tag> Tags { get; set; }

        public User() {
            Tags = new HashSet<Tag>();
        }

    }

[JsonObject(IsReference = true)]
public class Tag
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }

}
```

When I query my db:

```
    [Route("users")]
    [HttpGet]
    public IHttpActionResult getAllUsers()
    {
        var db = new PeopleOfIvantiContext();
        var users = db.Users.ToList();

        return Json( users);
    }
```

I get additional `$id`

```
[
   {
      "$id": "1",
      "Tags": [
         {
            "$id": "2",
            "Users": [
               {
                  "$ref": "1"
               }
            ],
            "Id": "4075f6ee-1073-4567-af27-af08ceef3d14",
            "Name": "SQL"
         },
         {
            "$id": "3",
            "Users": [
               {
                  "$ref": "1"
               }
            ],
            "Id": "4075f6ee-1073-4567-af27-af08ceef3d44",
            "Name": "c#"
         }
      ],
      "id": "4072a7f6-d02b-46ed-8da4-42e37bc47c57",
      "name": "Adam Kowalsky",
      "picture": "YOUR DATA HERE",
      "email": "Adam.kowalsky@gmail.com",
      "skypeLink": "YOUR DATA HERE",
      "title": "Social Worker",
      "location": {
         "imagename": "on.png",
         "x": 10,
         "y": 10
      },
      "products": "Google, Yahoo",
      "organizationUnit": "A",
      "skills": "C#",
      "hobbies": "Running, Reading"
   },
   {
```

How to get rid of these `$id`?

Comment: How did you produce that json? Just returned it from the controller?

Comment: Could it be that the same *instances* are added multiple times to the lists, and referred to by other objects, so that the json serialized tries to consolidate this and not duplicate the json? You have `IsReference = true` in there, what does that do?

Comment: See https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/PreserveObjectReferences.htm - you've explicitly asked for this with that attribute.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen If I don't do this I get `JSON.NET Error Self referencing loop detected for type`

Comment: Yes, so you need to solve your issue then. You can't serialize a self referencing loop and not add the references, your request doesn't make sense. How do you *want* it to be serialized? Do you want it to *ignore* the references? Then break the loop.

Comment: FYI, it's a bad decision to serialize a user with his tags, and each tag serializes a list of the users with that tag. You should break the loop, reconstruct the data during deserialization, remove the duplication during serialization, then you can break the loop.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen I want it to follow the reference one level deep and don't go further.l

Comment: Don't serialize the Users collection of the tags, or serialize something similar to a reference, such as a collection of user id's, just not the actual user.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen But I need that information I want a JSON of a User with his tags, and on the other endpoint tags with its users.

Comment: But you cannot serialize a user with the tags, and for each tag serialize a list of users, in which the same user occurs, which has the tag, which has the user, which has the tag, which has the user. Break the loop, change your serialization so that you stop at some level.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen I get it, and I would like to tell seliarizer to go exactly one level deep.

Comment: How about simply applying `[JsonIgnore]` to the `Users` collection of the `Tag` type?

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen I figured out how to solve this problem, take a look at my answer please.

Comment: I saw it, and I wonder if you're going to get exactly what you want, I'd be watchful of *where* it breaks the loop as you've basically just told Json.Net "figure it out for me".

Answer (score 1):

I figured out how to solve it

```
[Route("users")]
    [HttpGet]
    public IHttpActionResult GetAllUsers()
    {
        var db = new PeopleOfIvantiContext();
        var users = db.Users.ToList();
        var js = new JsonSerializerSettings();
        js.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
        return Json(users, js);
    }
```